# Symfony form collection and doctrine remove all children from a collection (unwanted)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I have two entities `order` and `orderdetail`. The are connected by a one-to-many-relationship.

**Order.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrderDetail", mappedBy="order", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $orderDetails;
```

**OrderDetail.php**

```
/**
 * The order this detail is in.
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Order", inversedBy="orderDetails")
 */
private $order;
```

When I edit an order, I want to be able to delete one or more details and save the order. Details should not exists on their own.

**What I have done so far**

I added `orphanRemoval=true` to make sure a detail cannot exist on it's own and `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` so that it is possible to remove a detail from the order.

In my form for my order **OrderType.php** I added the embedded for with the option `'allow_delete' => true,`

```
    ->add('orderDetails', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type' => OrderDetailType::class,
    'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'required'     => false,
    'by_reference' => false,
))
```

I added some jQuery to make it possible to delete a `orderDetail`, not relevant though because without it I have the same problem, which is: 
**whenever I edit an order and save, all order details are removed from that order and deleted from the database.**

The strange thing is that if I dump my `order` object in the controller before flushing everything looks exactly how it should. The moment `$entityManager->flush();` is executed the problem occurs.

Changes to my controller did not have any effect. Even when I remove just about all code in my controller, I remove the jQuery, I edit an order without touching anything and I save; all details are deleted.

Can you tell what causes this behaviour and how to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what caused the problem. I had form fields in the `order detail` that were disabled. These disabled fields were not sent to the server by my browser. This causes doctrine to remove those children. There has been some discussion on this issue [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18998).

In order to still have field that cannot be changed, but are still visible I removed the `disabled` attribute and added the attribute `readonly => true` to those form fields and my problem is resolved.